# Error while injecting Firebase as a Service in Component. What can be the issue?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am having problem in fetching data from the firebase service. I have a method called getListing. This is my service class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

  listings: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(private af: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getListings(){
    console.log('In getListings');
    this.listings = this.af.list('/listings') as FirebaseListObservable<Listing[]>;
    return this.listings;
  }

}

interface Listing{
  $key?:string;
  title?:string;
  type?:string;
  image?:string;
  city?:string;
  owner?:string;
  bedrooms?:string;
}
```

This is the component where I am Injecting the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseService } from '../../services/firebase.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listings',
  templateUrl: './listings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listings.component.css']
})
export class ListingsComponent implements OnInit {
  listings:any;

  constructor(private firebaseService:FirebaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firebaseService.getListings().subscribe(listings => {
      console.log(listings);
      this.listings = listings;
    });
  }

}
```

I am able to login using Google authentication and then when I try to call the getListing method in Service, I don't get a list of data. I am logging the list in the Console. The console log doesn't have any data. What could be the issue? I am injecting the service in the constructor of the Component and I have imported the Service from the services folder.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: did you have any errors in the console?

Comment: what errors you are getting?